# Automatic node finding not working

Tags: polymer

I am trying to run the following program (inspired from the sample [project](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-4.html)). I want to access the `loveCount_{{post.uid}}` span element and increment it by one whenever favorite is tapped.

```
<post-card
      favorite="{{post.favorite}}"
      on-favorite-tap="{{handleFavorite}}"
      hidden?="{{show == 'favorites' && !post.favorite}}">
      <img src="../images/{{post.avatar}}.svg" width="70" height="70">
      <h2>{{post.username}}</h2>
      <p>{{post.text}}</p>
      <p class="loveCount"><span id="loveCount_{{post.uid}}">{{post.loveCount}}</span></p>
</post-card>

<script>
 Polymer({
  handleFavorite: function(event, detail, sender) {
  var post = sender.templateInstance.model.post;

  if(post.favorite) {
    //hardcoding uid = '1', just to check if its working, but its not!
    console.log(this.$.loveCount_1);
  }
  this.$.service.setFavorite(post.uid, post.favorite);
  }
 });

</script>
```

Any idea where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do I need to use data binding here?

Comment: Apart from Jeff's answer, which is the correct way to solve your poroblem:
With ShadowDom there is no need to manually create a unique id. 
If you have only one `span` you can safely name it `loveCount` because it is encapsulated inside that instance and won't conflict with any other `post-card` instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're thinking about it the wrong way; as you suggest in your comment, data binding is the answer.

There are a few different places in which you could wire the data binding together; a very straightforward approach would be to define a `loveCount` property on each `<post-card>`, display that value in the `<template>` for `<post-card>`, and then increment the value in the `favoriteTapped` handler.

You can see the changes on lines 50, 55, and 63 of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jeffposnick/12722f81faef79e28f21).

More in keeping with the example, you might want to define `loveCount` as a property of each item the `posts.json` file that gets read in, or deal with displaying `loveCount` from within the template at `<post-list>`. There are lots of ways you could structure things, and it really depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, +1 for the Gist :)